# Где сказуемое в предложении "на улице погода прекрасная"?

Tags: синтаксис

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от синтаксической роли и позиции в предложении выражения НА УЛИЦЕ.
Если бы предложение выглядело так: ПОГОДА НА УЛИЦЕ [есть] ПРЕКРАСНАЯ, тогда сказуемое было бы ПРЕКРАСНАЯ, логическое ударение подчёркивает это. НА УЛИЦЕ - несогласованное определение (погода КАКАЯ?). 
(Где?)НА УЛИЦЕ [есть] ПОГОДА ПРЕКРАСНАЯ (НА УЛИЦЕ - обстоятельство перед отсутствующим глаголом ЕСТЬ. Всё изменилось: смысловой акцент сместился на обстоятельство НА УЛИЦЕ. Что на ней есть? ПОГОДА ПРЕКРАСНАЯ. Подлежащее "погода". Сказуемого нет(глагол ЕСТЬ опущен). Это неполное предложение. "Прекрасная" здесь ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ, несмотря на то что оно стоит после определяемого слова.

***Сказуемого в Вашем предложении нет. Это неполное предложение.***

Comment: Не могу с Вами согласиться. НА УЛИЦЕ -обстоятельство, это верно. Но дальше Вы почему-то задаете вопрос от обстоятельства к подлежащему, а не от сказуемого к обстоятельству, как это по всем правилам положено. ПРЕКРАСНАЯ - это слово было бы определением в препозиции, но не в постпозиции,как в данном предложении. Значит, рассуждаем просто: погода - подлежащее (что говорится о подлежащем "погода"? - погода прекрасная. Где погода прекрасная? На улице. Это двусоставное распространенное предложение

Comment: Вы не поняли: вопрос задаётся к обстоятельству именно от сказуемого ЕСТЬ. Его просто нет в предложении, и вопрос "зависает".

Comment: Катя, уточните, пожалуйста свою позицию. Есть - это связка? Тогда что она связывает?

Comment: Лара, спасибо, Вы правы, я не должна была так легкомысленно характеризовать ЕСТЬ во второй части своего ответа. Правлю.

Comment: Считаю необходимым согласиться. И немного проиллюстрировать:

1. __На Дерибасовской прекрасная погода__ (/была прекрасная погода) - здесь утверждается существование погоды (уж подлежащее она там или главный член односоставного - вопрос не об этом), а _прекрасная_ - просто определение.

2. __Погода была прекрасная__ [принцесса была - ужжасная!] - сообщается о свойстве погоды. Т.е. погода - о чём говорится в предложении - подлежащее; а то, что говорится о подлежащем (_прекрасная_), - сказуемое.

Comment: Ну вот! А мой ответ отвергли!

Comment: Да! Да! Отверг! Не всегда инверсия радикально меняет грамматику. Иногда это просто фигура речи. "На севере диком стоит одиноко..."

==============================

Справедливость требует, конечно, сказать, что в исходном примере возможны оба варианта (_прекрасная_ - определение и _прекрасная_ - сказуемое). Это уже зависит от намерений автора и может быть определено только интонацией или какими-нибудь там авторскими тире (_На улице - погода прекрасная!_ // _На улице погода - прекрасная!_)...

Answer (score 0):

Сказуемое - прилагательное "прекрасная". Полное прилагательное является сказуемым, если оно стоит после подлежащего, а глагола в предложении нет.

Answer (score 0):

Это назывное предложение, в котором "хлеб" - подлежащее, а "теплый" - определение. Если бы предложение выглядело так: "Хлеб теплый", то слово "теплый" было бы сказуемым.

Answer (score 0):

"На улице погода прекрасная". Только так не говорят, предложение построено неверно, нужно изменить актуальное членение:

ПогОда на улице (пауза) прекрАсная. Сравнить: Погода на улице была прекрасная. И никаких вопросов: составное именное сказуемое, именная часть выражена прилагательным, нулевая связка.